# Bluetooth, Network and Phone Call Functions at the same time?

Tags: android, networking, bluetooth

I am developing a system and want an Android phone working in the system.

I am wondering if a Android app can do these three things at the same time

1)  Reveiving data from a Bluetooth device using SPP profile.

2)  Send the data (reveived from the Bluetooth device) to an IP address visa the network (not WIFI)

3) Make a phone call when the app is running in the background.

Assume the network supports the voice and data at the same time and the smart phone has the Bluetooth function.

If this kind of app is realizable?

Thanks

Comment: Just a heads up... CDMA (verizon, sprint) phones can't do cellular data connections and phone calls at the same time. Wifi, maybe, 3g/4G/LTEwhateveryouwanttocallit, no.

Comment: You mean 3G/4G/LTE support voice and data at the same time right?

Answer (score 0):

YES - you can.
Even if the phone call is handled by Bluetooth via a Bluetooth Headset connection , it is possible to do all this simultaneously

Comment: Hi Dennis~ Thannk you very much for your reply. Totoally no offence. Could you let me know where I can find something like "Android smart phones support these three functions at the same time" on a paper? Like an Android Specification or any white paper. Thank you again.